# What is a better way to organize ssh deploy keys?

Tags: git, github, ssh, debian

I am workin with Debian Wheezy and have multiple private git repositories deployed into my environment. ie the Rails api, rubygems, javascript frontend, statsd, etc. Each repo requires a unique ssh private/public deploy key pair, and I have managed each key with a `.ssh/config` file and aliases. This technique was fine when I only had 3 repos, but now I have nearly 10 and the config file is getting lengthy.

Is there a better way to organize my ssh deploy keys? Maybe a system that doesn't require aliases??

Comment: Why does each repository require a unique key?

Comment: Github does not allow the same key to be used more than once.

Comment: Are you using a different GitHub account for each repository?

Comment: The repos are all owned by the organization.

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem. I have access to many repositories across many organizations, and I don't need a different SSH key for each one. I've generally got one per *machine*, not one per repository.

Comment: Locally I can access all of them. I can not set the same deploy key more than once.

Comment: Ah, we're talking about *deploy* keys, not user keys! That's completely different, and I don't think it was clear in your question.

Comment: Cheers, Chris. I updated my question. Thank you for your responses.